# Custom API response HTTP status codes with ABP Framework

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

Is there any way to return custom HTTP Status Codes (like 4xx) with ASP.NET Boilerplate?

I would like to set custom application specific HTTP codes in context of validation to add more granularity. Currently ABP would set 200(OK) for all validation errors.

In ABP source code is see few places like one below where `Response.StatusCode` is set by the framework like here :

```
    private void HandleAndWrapException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!ActionResultHelper.IsObjectResult(context.ActionDescriptor.GetMethodInfo().ReturnType))
        {
            return;
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(
            new AjaxResponse(
                _errorInfoBuilder.BuildForException(context.Exception),
                context.Exception is AbpAuthorizationException
            )
        );

        context.Exception = null; //Handled!
    }
```

Comment: I think only `[DontWrapResult]` can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I eventually did was replace ABP exception filter altogether. In my custom filter I could set any status code I need.

```
var filters = Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().HttpConfiguration.Filters;
var currentExceptionFilter = filters
    .First(h => h.Instance is AbpExceptionFilterAttribute).Instance;

filters.Remove(currentExceptionFilter );
filters.Add(IocManager.Resolve<MyApiExceptionFilter>());
```

Comment: For security purposes all exceptions and errors should be sent to client with HTTP-200 (or with any 2xx success results). The reason for that; attackers like DDOS makers like the exception pages and the scan urls to get any http error. DDOS attacks can be easily done with the exception page is flooded.

Comment: @edgars-pivovarenoks Pivovarenoks? =))) what is the origin of this surname?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **UserFriendlyException** we allows you to pass response code.
Example: throw new **UserFriendlyException**(302, "Redirecting...");

Comment: There is no such signature in ABP Framework :( And what ABP Framework offers now is supplying custom code inside some hardcoded HTTP code value, e.g. 403 ("409", "Custom error text")