# Custom HTTP response in ASP.NET Core 2.x Boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to throw my own custom exceptions from within an `AppService`. Included with the exception being thrown, I would like to add my own HTTP status. Regardless of the various methods specified on Stackoverflow as well as other sources, I'm unable to override the default functionality of ASP.NET Boilerplate. Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom API response HTTP status codes with ABP Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38219222/8601760)

Comment: Nope, that implementation uses MVC boilerplate and not aspnet core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `AbpExceptionFilter` (or implement your own `IExceptionFilter`) and then add it:

**Step 1**

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.AddService(typeof(MyExceptionFilter), order: 1);
});
```

**Step 2**
Add the following code in the `XYZWebHostModule` class:

```cs
        public override void PreInitialize()
        {
            Configuration.ReplaceService(typeof(IExceptionFilter),
                () =>
                {
                    IocManager.Register<IExceptionFilter, MyExceptionFilter>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
                });
        }
```

**Step 3**
Subclass `AbpExceptionFilter` and override `GetStatusCode` as well as `HandleAndWrapException`, based on your requirements and implementations

#### References

- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3280
- https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#exception-filter

Comment: Working day is all but over, I'll give it a shot tommorow morning. Many thanks for the response!